# Splunk search on computed column

Tags: splunk

I'm trying to search result set computed column based upon a text box token in a dashboard. A simplified version of one of my attempts at the XML definition is below:

```
 </input>
    <input type="text" token="ID" searchWhenChanged="true">
        <label>BIB ID</label>
    <default>*</default>
 </input>
</fieldset>
<row>
    <table>
    <title>Customer</title>
    <search>
      <query>sourcetype="source type" | eval "ID"=substr('FullID',21,29) | 
        where "ID"="$ID$"
      </query> (...)
```

I've tried a number of ways of dynamically assigning a value from the text box to filter ID by $ID$ in each of the pipelines, but nothing so far works.

Comment: Have you tried `search` instead of `where`? See https://answers.splunk.com/answers/128739/difference-between-where-and-search-commands.html for more info.